# How do you localize WatchKit menu items?

Tags: ios, watchkit

My WatchKit app is all localized using NSLocalizedString in code except for the items in my force touch menu. I am using storyboards and interface builder doesn't seem to be able to give me a reference to either the menu or the items. Does anyone know how we are supposed to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always create your menu items programatically, bypassing the storyboard altogether, which would allow you to easily use localized strings. Check out the documentation for `addMenuItemWithImage:title:action:` and the like: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/addMenuItemWithImage:title:action: